# Referring to an array inside a PHP Object while defining the object

Tags: php, arrays, object

I have this object definition

```
return (object) [
    // the database information
    'db_info' => [
        'type' => 'mysql',
        'server' => 'localhost',
        'database' => 'myshop',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => 'password',
        'tableprefix' => 'password',
        'charset' => 'password'
    ],
    // the database tables
    'tables_info' => [
        'tblcountries' => db_info.database . '.'. db_info.tableprefix . 'countries',
        'tblsettings' => db_info.database . '.'. db_info.tableprefix . 'settings'
    ]
]
```

I am trying to use some of the array defined inside the same object

that is in the tables_info array

```
'tblcountries' => db_info.database . '.'. db_info.tableprefix . 'countries`
```

Is it possible, if yes how..

Comment: No, until you get to the end of the piece the object does not exist so there is nothing to reference, even if you referenced it correctly with `->`

Comment: The possible way to access that array of object is to define an variable above like $db_info with the value then cast it to object, so you can use it on tables_info like $db_info->database, etc..

Comment: Note that the `(object)` cast is not recursive. The `db_info` property is an associative array, not an object.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in 2 steps like this

```
$obj =  (object) [
        'db_info' => [
            'type' => 'mysql',
            'server' => 'localhost',
            'database' => 'myshop',
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => 'password',
            'tableprefix' => 'password',
            'charset' => 'password'
        ]
    ];


$obj->table_info = [
    'tblcountries' => $obj->db_info['database'] . '.' . $obj->db_info['tableprefix'] . 'countries',
    'tblsettings' => $obj->db_info['database'] . '.'. $obj->db_info['tableprefix'] . 'settings'
];

print_r($obj);
```

RESULT

```
stdClass Object
(
    [db_info] => Array
        (
            [type] => mysql
            [server] => localhost
            [database] => myshop
            [username] => root
            [password] => password
            [tableprefix] => password
            [charset] => password
        )
    [table_info] => Array
        (
            [tblcountries] => myshop.passwordcountries
            [tblsettings] => myshop.passwordsettings
        )
)
```

Or if you wanted everything to be an object rather that an object with arrays in

```
$obj =  (object) [
        'db_info' => (object) [
            'type' => 'mysql',
            'server' => 'localhost',
            'database' => 'myshop',
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => 'password',
            'tableprefix' => 'password',
            'charset' => 'password'
            ]
        ];

$obj->table_info = (object) [
    'tblcountries' => $obj->db_info->database . '.' . $obj->db_info->tableprefix . 'countries',
    'tblsettings' => $obj->db_info->database . '.'. $obj->db_info->tableprefix . 'settings'
];

print_r($obj);
```

RESULT

```
stdClass Object
(
    [db_info] => stdClass Object
        (
            [type] => mysql
            [server] => localhost
            [database] => myshop
            [username] => root
            [password] => password
            [tableprefix] => password
            [charset] => password
        )
    [table_info] => stdClass Object
        (
            [tblcountries] => myshop.passwordcountries
            [tblsettings] => myshop.passwordsettings
        )
)
```

Comment: Yep, it worked fine..  Using the first method for a configuration file.